# Move 3d plot on the xy plane

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to plot my data, but my 3d plot is out of bounds, meaning its above the z-axis 0 point. I want it to be on the xy plane, meaning an offset of -160. Is there a way of adding an offset?
This is an image of what I am trying to achieve
[image]

My code:

```
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set(xlim=(-3, 2), ylim=(0.25, 2), zlim=(-160, 0), xlabel='CV1', ylabel='CV2', zlabel='free energy (kJ/mol)')

ax.plot_surface(xvals, yvals, zvals, edgecolor='royalblue', lw=0.8, rstride=1, cstride=1,alpha=0.3, cmap= 'plasma')

ax.contour(xvals, yvals, zvals, zdir='z', offset= -160, cmap='plasma')
plt.savefig('myplot.png')
plt.show()
```

(The x_vals, y_vals, z_vals are reshaped ndarrays, their shape((101,101))

I searched the documentation of the plot_surface function but could not find a way to add some offset.